# Wordpress: Custom URL

Tags: php, wordpress

At front end I fetches some links from mysql db table like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/my_site/detail/Link-1">Link 1</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/my_site/detail/Link-2">Link 2</a>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost/my_site/detail/Link-3">Link 3</a>
```

and from admin side **Setting -> Permalink** I set `http://localhost/sparcs/sample-post/`
and also create a page and named **detail** whose url is exactly **http://localhost/my_site/detail/**

but when I click to any links WP says

> Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps
>   searching will help.

though I could use `<a href="http://localhost/my_site/detail/3">Link 3</a>` and it works fine & I could get url info using `pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`.

Actually I create custom url in by db table and then show these url on my WP page leftbar and want if I click it wp show the page and I could be able to catch url info with `pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

I also used **Custom Structure** and set `http://localhost/my_site/detail/url` but not work.

I think it might be solve using

> rewrite.php
>   in `wp-includes/rewrite.php`

but I don't know how & which function should be modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I discover the solution:

http://webspot-msajid.blogspot.com/2012/07/creating-seo-friendly-urls-with-merger.html